# Create a Vector of Integers and missing Values

Tags: julia

What a hazzle...

I'm trying to create a vector of `integer`s and `missing` values. This works fine:

```
b = [4, missing, missing, 3]
```

But I would actually like the vector to be longer with more `missing` values and therefore use `repeat()`, but this doesn't work

```
append!([1,2,3], repeat([missing], 1000))
```

and this also doesn't work

```
[1,2,3, repeat([missing], 1000)]
```

Please, help me out, here.

Comment: I suggest writing `fill(missing, 1000)` rather than `repeat([missing], 1000)`. It is more idiomatic, and on my computer, at least, approximately 200x faster.

Comment: Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is also worth to note that if you do not need to do an in-place operation with `append!` actually in such cases it is much easier to do vertical concatenation:

```
julia> [[1, 2, 3]; repeat([missing], 2); 4; 5] # note ; that denotes vcat
7-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 1
 2
 3
  missing
  missing
 4
 5

julia> vcat([1,2,3], repeat([missing], 2), 4, 5) # this is the same but using a different syntax
7-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 1
 2
 3
  missing
  missing
 4
 5
```

The benefit of `vcat` is that it automatically does the type promotion (as opposed to `append!` in which case you have to correctly specify the `eltype` of the target container before the operation).

---

Note that because `vcat` does automatic type promotion in corner cases you might get a different `eltype` of the result of the operation:

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> append!(x, [1.0, 2.0]) # conversion from Float64 to Int happens here
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 1
 2

julia> [[1, 2, 3]; [1.0, 2.0]] # promotion of Int to Float64 happens in this case
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0
 1.0
 2.0
```

See also https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-array-literals.

Comment: Thanks. Even though both answers work, I think this is the more elegant one. (That might be the case, since I come from `R`.)

Comment: And normally it is a preferred approach (unless you want to do an in-place updating of an existing collection). I have added a small note that I hope will show you the corner-case scenario that one should be aware of when deciding to use `append!` vs `vcat`.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
append!(Union{Int,Missing}[1,2,3], repeat([missing], 1000))
```

`[1,2,3]` creates just a `Vector{Int}` and since Julia is strongly typed the  `Vector{Int}` cannot accept values of non-`Int` type. Hence, when defining a structure, that you plan to hold more data types within, you need to explicitly state it - here we have defined `Vector{Union{Int,Missing}}`.